# Crystal Reports Show Sum Result Value in Another Part of Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have sumerize by group, and now i'm trying to join all those results in the bottom of the report. The only thing that i can do is to get the total in the footer, but i just wanna the total of that group. Dont know if has a simple way to do that.

I wanna link the result of the SUM in the report footer, separated by group.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify. Perhaps use an example so it is easier to follow.

If you need a compact display of group sums in the report footer, insert a CrossTab in the Report Footer section.